# request.method == 'POST' not working properly

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i have created quiz app in which i created three models ( Quiz, Question ,Answer) ,Question have Foreignkey to Quiz and Answer have Foreignkey to Question.i have provided booleanfield to correct ans.
Now i created view which redirect to next question if user choose correct ans or else redirect to start
But its not properly working.

Here is my code
Views.py

```
def question_detail(request,question_id,quiz_id):
q = Quiz.objects.get(pk = quiz_id)
que = Question.objects.get(pk = question_id)
count = q.question_set.count()
if request.method == 'POST':
    selected = que.answer_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    if selected is True :
        try:
            come  = que.rank
            came = come +1
            later_question = q.question_set.get(rank=came)
        except:
            come = que.rank
            came = come
            later_question = q.question_set.get(rank=came)
    else :
        come = que.rank
        later_question = q.question_set.get(rank=come)
    return render(request,'app/question_detail.html',{'count':count,'que':que,'later_question':later_question})
else:
    return render(request,'app/result.html')
```

Comment: So do you indent the code properly?

Comment: Ye even i improvised in my view but it still not work as i wanted.         Here is my views.py.    https://pastebin.com/MmSpegL8